# Decoupling a Configuration API in an Embedded Framework

Tags: object-oriented, c++, api-design, embedded-systems

In my embedded project I am designing a framework that allows the user to create widgets at compile time. All widgets must provide the same base functionality. Further, there are multiple widget categories which may share common code.

The user is supposed to create instances of the specific implementations ("the startup configuration") and then pass them to the `GenericClient`, which is written against the abstractions. Additionally, it is required that `ConfigurationClient` has access to the `Configure` methods for external (re-)configuration at runtime. My naive design approach looks like this:

[image: Simplified design]

And the corresponding implementation is similar to:

`user/Configuration.cpp` (this is the file the user should edit)

```cpp
#include "framework/GenericClient.hpp"
#include "framework/ConfigurationClient.hpp"
#include "framework/Widgets.hpp"

Impl1 widgetOne{1,2,3};
Impl2 widgetTwo{200};
Impl2 widgetThree{400};

constexpr Impl1* impl1Instances[]{&widgetOne};
constexpr Impl2* impl2Instances[]{&widgetTwo, &widgetThree};
constexpr WidgetCategory1* c1Instances[]{&widgetOne, &widgetTwo, &widgetThree};
constexpr IWidget* widgets[]{&widgetOne, &widgetTwo, &widgetThree};

ConfigurationClient confClient{impl1Instances, impl2Instances};
GenericClient genericClient{widgets, c1Instances};

void GetConfiguration(ConfigurationClient** cc, GenericClient** gc)
{
    *cc = confClient;
    *gc = genericClient;
}
```

`framework/main.cpp`

```cpp
#include "framework/ConfigurationClient.hpp"
#include "framework/GenericClient.hpp"

void GetConfiguration(ConfigurationClient** cc, GenericClient** gc);

int main()
{
    ConfigurationClient* confClient;
    GenericClient* genericClient;
    
    GetConfiguration(&confClient, &genericClient);
    
    if (!confClient || !genericClient) return;
    
    while(true)
    {
        confClient.ProcessIncomingData();
        genericClient.ProcessWidgets();
    }
}
```

`framework/Widgets.hpp`

```cpp
// IWidget and WidgetCategory1 declarations

class Impl1 : public WidgetCategory1
{
public:
    Configure(int a, int b);
};

class Impl2 : public WidgetCategory1
{
public:
    Configure(bool z);
};
```

`GenericClient.hpp`

```cpp
// Written against more generic interface types.
// Must be able to iterate over all widgets and widget categories.
class GenericClient
{
public:
    void ProcessWidgets(); 

private:
    std::span<WidgetCategory1*const> c1Instances;
    std::span<IWidget*const> widgets;
};
```

`ConfigurationClient.hpp`

```cpp
// Written against specific types. 
// Must be able to call the ConfigureX implementations.
class ConfigurationClient
{
public:
    // Data is provided via UART during runtime
    void ReConfigureWidgets(std::span<uint8_t> data); 

private:
    std::span<Impl1*const> impl1Instances;
    std::span<Impl2*const> impl2Instances;
};
```

This implementation requires the user to write redundant list entries in `user/Configuration.cpp`.

In order to reduce the user's workload, I could merge the `Client` classes and depend on the specific widget types for all operations. Alternatively, I could introduce a common configuration method (i.e. `void Configure(size_t index, int value)`) to `IWidget` making `ConfigurationClient` superfluous.

In my opinion, the first solution violates the design principle to separate the things that change (new widget implementations) from what stays the same (widget categories and overall processing). The second solution is not as strongly typed as having separate `Configure` methods.

*I am in search for a design that allows me to keep the separation and have strongly typed `Configure` methods.*

If you think these goals are impractical, I am interested in alternatives and feedback (e.g. why is it a bad idea to separate `ConfigurationClient` and `GenericClient`), too.

Comment: Since configuration is pretty implementation dependend, I'm not sure why you want to have a generic `ConfigurationClient`. Wouldn't the end-user create fully configured widgets? Can you provide some more detail (pseudo-code maybe) how this would be used and what `ConfigurationClient` does?

Comment: As @RobertBräutigam points out it's not currently clear how widget construction is independent from widget configuration wrt your scenario. In cases where they are separate, it's usually a matter of one system or subsystem customizing another in which case you may well want a templated function which would probably be passed via a lambda for convenience.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam @aluan-haddad Thanks for your feedback. Widget (re-)configuration takes place after the widget has been constructed. The necessary data is sent via UART and deserialized by `ConfigurationClient`. I refactored the code example and rephrased the question to clarify my motivation for this question.